# How to make form fields required?

Tags: php, forms

I have this existing code and I am wondering how to make the name and email field required?

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "xxx@email.com"; // this is your Email address
$from = $_POST['gift_email']; // this is the sender's Email address
$first_name = $_POST['gift_name'];
$subject = "Free Gift Request";
$msg = "A free gift has been requested from the following:"."\n";
$msg .= "Name: ".$_POST["gift_name"]."\n";
$msg .= "E-Mail: ".$_POST["gift_email"];

$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
//echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";

header('Location:free_program_thankyou.php'); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Googling your title = *About 1,770,000 results (0.31 seconds)*

Answer (score 3):

**For form**

```
<input type="text" name="gift_email" required>
<input type="text" name="gift_name" required>
```

**For Php**

```
 if(empty($_POST['gift_email']))
    {
    echo 'This field is required';
    }else {
//Do what you want to do here
}
```

Comment: it's `$_POST` not `$_post` and your missing a semi-colon

Comment: `$_POST` is a [**superglobal**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and **must** be in uppercase.

Comment: You forgot the semi-colon. It will throw a parse error.

Comment: You're welcome, always glad to help out, *cheers* - P.s.: There's nothing wrong with your English.

Comment: Unfortunately the empty approach will not work when 0 is an acceptable value.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Right, just noting the limitations of empty as a new PHP user will undoubtedly attempt to use it elsewhere he needs to check for required fields.

Comment: @KevinMark No, entering `0` in a test did not accept the value. PHP interprets it as NULL/EMPTY. However it is best using [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) in conjunction with `empty()` for Emails.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 I always like to test things out before, that way the "proof is in the pudding", *as it were*. ;) Kevin made a good point that was worth looking into, but alas, `0` was not accepted by PHP. However, entering `1` was accepted, so best to use `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` also for Emails, which seems to be the case for the OP.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I believe there was some miscommunication. I wasn't critiquing the use of `empty` in this particular situation (although it is not ideal) I was just noting that `empty` is quite liberal in its definition of empty. 0 as an acceptable value was just an example of valid input (for some fields) that is considered invalid via `empty`.

Comment: @KevinMark I understand Kevin.

Answer (score 1):

A two basic ways to do this:-

- Within the php program check each required form field has been filled in send a new page with an error message back if it is not. Be sure to return the contents of any fields already filled in or your users will wish a plague of boils on your person.
- Validate in javascript. Have a function triggered by the "onsubmit" condition which checks for all required forms fields are filled and highlights any that are not. see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp)

In practice a robust web site will do both. This seems like duplication however the javascript function is much more responsive and user friendly, BUT, the php server side validation cannot be gamed by turning JS off or spoofing responses.

Comment: html5 gives new options